# Iterating orver tuples in a databag

Tags: apache-pig

I have a relation in the following format
A=(charrarry,{})
where A is groups of databags. Each databag has some tuples and each tuple has five fields. How can I iterate over the tuples of the databag and also how can I sort each group based on the first tuple field.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give example input and output or explain what you want to achieve by iterating or sorting the tuples?

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this: 
`(all,{(1.0,10.0),(4.0,12.0),(2.0,13.0),(3.0,14.0)})`

You do not need to explicitly iterate over the entire bag, you can just sort it like so:
`data = LOAD 'cor.txt' AS (series1:double, series2:double);`
`rel = GROUP data ALL;`
`--Now rel has the data as shown above`
`rel = FOREACH rel GENERATE FLATTEN(data);`
`rel = ORDER rel by data::series1;`
`dump rel;`

Output:
`(1.0,10.0)`
`(2.0,13.0)`
`(3.0,14.0)`
`(4.0,12.0)`

If you have another level of nesting, use `FLATTEN` appropriately.

(An example in your problem statement would have made it easier for everyone!)